# Oracle built-in function to present float value

Tags: oracle, plsql, truncate

I wrote this statement:

```
TRUNC (v_Valutazione, 2);
```

because I have a v_Valutazione value like this:

```
-,9165786879898
```

In this way, with the trunc function, I obtain -,91.

I want instead something like -,92 .

Is this possible with one function?

Comment: try this `select ROUND(-.9165786879898,2) from dual`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word you are looking for, sir, is `round()`